# how to not get null values from ngrx store

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am using nrgx/store package in angular 7.

This is kind  of way how I get this currentAdAccount from store. the thing is I have this piece of code in multiple components. Now this piece of code is wrong because, something else that puts this value into store doesn't happen that fast and so this piece of code below at the first 1ms it returns null; then after 10ms, it returns the correct value. so In order to make this work, I gotta add this : `if(!currentAdAccount) return;` in the subscribe .

```
this.store.select(fromRoot.currentAdAccount).subscribe(currentAdAccount => {
      console.log("nice1", currentAdAccount);
     this.currentAdAccountId = currentAdAccount.value;
    })
```

So,in every place, it's not good to write if statements and checking the value is not null.

QUestion 1) how do I only get values that are not null in a very easy way so that it doesn't get duplicated?

QUestion 2) how do you deal with these kind of situations?

Answer (score 3):

You can write it like this

```js
this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.currentAdAccount), skip(1))
```

In order for this code to work, you have to set the initial state for currentAdAccount in reducer like this

```js
export const initialState = {
 currentAdAccount: null
}
```

and also use async pipe in your view

You have this problem

> so this piece of code below at the first 1ms it returns null; then
>   after 10ms, it returns the correct value

because the state has to init the initial value in the first time you load the page and after that, the reducer will fetch the new state from the store base on your action.

Please let me know if you have any problem

Comment: so this means that I still have to write if statement when subscribing to store value. THat was my question how to avoid if statements in subscribe .

Comment: Please read my answer carefully. I'm using skip so that I can skip null value at first time

Comment: Cool. THis will work. Are you sure this is the best practice and it's not possible that first value might not be null? In my opinion, this will work flawlessly. I am just also asking you if this is the best practice.

Comment: We do like this in our current project

Answer (score 3):

You can filter null values with `.pipe(filter(val => val !== null)).subscribe(currentAdAccount => ...))`. The NgRx docs describe a [best practice to extract select-and-filter scenarios](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors#breaking-down-the-basics) as a pipeable operator:

```
import { select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

export const selectExistingCurrentAdAccount = pipe(
  select(fromRoot.currentAdAccount),
  filter(val => val !== null)
);
```

and use it like this:

```
this.store.pipe(selectExistingCurrentAdAccount).subscribe(currentAdAccount => ...)
```